# Register a file type using Visual Studio 2010 setup project

Tags: visual-studio-2010, installation

I need to register a file type (e.g. .exex files) when my application is installed because I want that when the user double clicks a .exex file to be automatically opened with my application. How can I do this using Visual Studio 2010 installer project?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's quite straight-forward to do:

1. Right-click the setup project in Solution Explorer and select *View -> File Types* from the context menu.
2. Right-click the *File Types on Target Machine* node to add a new file type
3. In the *Properties* window you may specify the properties of the file type: Enter the extension, a description and the command to open a file of this type.